# creating a block band diagonal matrix in sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I would like to create a block band diagonal matrix using `sympy`.
Basically, the matrix should look like

D N 0 0 0 0
R D N 0 0 0
0 R D N 0 0
0 0 R D N 0
0 0 0 R D N
0 0 0 0 R D

This matrix will then later be fed to `numpy` via `sympy.lambdify` and `numpy` will calculate the eigenvalues for many different parameter sets.
I did find a method to construct the matrix using `sympy.kronecker_product`, however, it is incredibly slow. I had a look at why my program is so slow and found that `kronecker.py` is the culprit. This was quite a surprise, as I thought diagonalizing a matrix would be the slowest part. Even more so as the matrix only needs to be constructed once and then is diagonalized very often.

Thus, I am looking for a way to contruct my matrix without using `sympy.kronecker_product`. Any advice is appreciated.

Here the example program:

```
import sympy
a,b,c,d = sympy.symbols('a b c d', real=True)
e,f,g,h = sympy.symbols('e f g h', real=True)

D = sympy.Matrix([[a,b-sympy.I*c],[b+sympy.I*c,d]])
#usually more complicated, with constants and sin/cos terms
N = sympy.Matrix([[e,sympy.I*f],[g,-sympy.I*h]])
R = sympy.adjoint(N)

size = 20 #usually around 100

H = sympy.kronecker_product(sympy.eye(size),D) \
  + sympy.kronecker_product(sympy.jordan_cell(0,size),N) \
  + sympy.kronecker_product(sympy.transpose(sympy.jordan_cell(0,size)),R)

H_numpy = sympy.lambdify((a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h), H, 'numpy')

import numpy
for i in range(10*size):
    eigenvalues = numpy.linalg.eigvalsh(H_numpy(i,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recently added `banded` might be a solution for you:

```
>>> size=3
>>> var('d n r')
(d, n, r)
```

With scalars

```
>>> banded(size,{0:d,1:n,-1:r})
Matrix([
[d, n, 0],
[r, d, n],
[0, r, d]])
```

With the matrices that you defined:

```
>>> banded(2*size, {0:D,2:N,-2:R})
Matrix([
[      a, b - I*c,       e,     I*f,       0,       0],
[b + I*c,       d,       g,    -I*h,       0,       0],
[      e,       g,       a, b - I*c,       e,     I*f],
[   -I*f,     I*h, b + I*c,       d,       g,    -I*h],
[      0,       0,       e,       g,       a, b - I*c],
[      0,       0,    -I*f,     I*h, b + I*c,       d]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks very awesome. I will get a development version of sympy and try it out.

Comment: `banded` is perfect! The speed gain is huge, my calculations are more than 5 times as fast (for larger matrices).

Comment: Thanks for that answer! I needed exactly that for calculating B-Splines.